# Signals in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-signals

I have 2 models.py files in different app directories: users.models.py and friends.models.py.

There is one problem: if some user deleted from UserProfile model, all his friendship network must be deleted too with him. It is very natural.

But when I import Frienship to users.model.py I've got an error: ***Cannot import name Friendship***

I understand an error arose because of mutual importing in these 2 files, and I know I can easely solve this problem with the help of signals, but I do not know how to do it in proper way.

Could anybody help in this particular case?

In users.models.py:

```
from friends.models import Friendship

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    username = models.Charfield(max_length=50)
    ...

    def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Friendship.objects.remove_all(self)
        self.delete(*args, **kwargs)
```

In friends.models.py:

```
from users.models import UserProfile

class FriendshipManager(models.Manager):
    def remove_all(self, user):
        usr = Friendship.objects.get(user=user).friends
        frs = [i.user for i in usr.all()]
        for fr in frs:
            usr.remove(fr)

class Friendship(models.Model):
    user = models.Foreignkey(UserProfile)
    friends = models.ManyToManyField('self')

    objects = FriendshipManager()
```

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: You're looking at it the wrong way. Circular imports are a sign of bad design. It's time to refactor, not time to find a workaround. Models this closely related should be part of the same app.

Comment: But than there would be a very large models.py file with more than 600 rows. I wanted to separate these classes...

Comment: He said same app, you are free to have as many separate model files in an app.. just give them a class Meta app_label and import them from the app basic __init__ file to make sure django "sees" them

Comment: I don't get it: what changed if there will be 1 app with different models files. Situation the same: circular imports between them... I do not understand how you propose prevent this with "Meta app_label and import them from the app basic init file to make sure django "sees" them"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for signals, just use the magic *_set property. It will be defined at runtime so you don't have to worry about circular imports.

**friends/models.py**

```
from users.models import UserProfile

class Friendship(models.Model):
    user = models.Foreignkey(UserProfile)
    friends = models.ManyToManyField('self')
```

**users/models.py**

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    username = models.Charfield(max_length=50)
    ...

    def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
        for f in self.friendship_set.all():
            f.delete()
        super(self.__class__, self).delete(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: and friendship_set is an automatic related_name for user field in Friendship class or what???

Answer (score 1):

This is what I usually do, you could easily refactor this to implement with your model

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.signals import post_save, post_delete
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# App specific


class UserProfile(models.Model):
    """
    Adds a basic UserProfile for each User on the fly.
    """
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to='example/somewhere', blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
          return "%s's profile" % self.user

    def get_avatar(self):
        return '/'+self.avatar

    def clean_avatar(self):
        # TODO: imagekit
        pass

    class Meta:
        app_label = 'users'

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.id:
            this = UserProfile.objects.get(id=self.id)
            if this.avatar:
                if this.avatar != self.avatar:
                    this.avatar.delete(save=False)
        super(UserProfile, self).save()

def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
       profile, created = UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=instance)

post_save.connect(create_user_profile, sender=User)


def UserProfileDelete(instance, **kwargs):
    """
    Documentatie
    """
    instance.avatar.delete(save=False)

post_delete.connect(UserProfileDelete, sender=UserProfile)
```